Not able to accesss me/accounts of Instagram Graph API
I am trying out the Instagram Graph API for the first time to get the user page ID, aiming to retrieve the Instagram business account ID. However, when I use the Graph tool for my app and enter me/accounts, it returns nothing. I read that me/accounts should return various data, including what I need, but it comes up empty despite fetching the access token properly.
I've had trouble finding updated documentation on the correct permissions needed for me/accounts. Some permissions don't seem to be available anymore. I've tried many permissions, but nothing works. Currently, I have the following permissions: pages_show_list, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, and pages_read_user_content. I also have a business Instagram account linked to my Facebook account.
Any advice on how to sort it?
I tried using graph apis and even in meta explore tools as well, but getting data as empty string on fteching me/accounts. I had linked instagram and facebook page and even turned instagram account into business account.
Expecting to get all the accounts linked, so that i can use id for content publishing.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the code (redacting whatever credentials you use) that you use to get the information with.
